# Preprocess Pascal VOc format custom dataset using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, object-detection, data-preprocessing

I have a pascal voc format dataset annotated with images and the objects they contain in different bounding boxes. I want to use this custom data from the directory to train an object recognition model on tensorflow. I am using Google Colab and my data directory is stored on Google Drive.

I want to use a pascal voc format dataset already split into train, test, valid subfolders. The images are annotated with bounding boxes and I want to prepare this datset to train a tensorflow  object detection model.
I believe the code parses my pascal voc format datset pretty well, and is able to return the class and bounding box dimensions. However, I can't convert it into a tf dataset object.

Below is the snippet to parse the directory(which is stored on Google Drive).

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
import tensorflow as tf

def parse_annotation(xml_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Extract image path
    image_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, root.find('filename').text)

    objects = []
    for obj in root.findall('object'):
        obj_dict = {}
        obj_dict['class'] = obj.find('name').text

        bbox = obj.find('bndbox')
        xmin = int(bbox.find('xmin').text)
        ymin = int(bbox.find('ymin').text)
        xmax = int(bbox.find('xmax').text)
        ymax = int(bbox.find('ymax').text)
        obj_dict['bbox'] = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

        objects.append(obj_dict)

    return image_path, objects
for folder in ['train', 'test', 'valid']:
    folder_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, folder)
    image_files = os.listdir(folder_path)

    for image_file in image_files:
        # Check if the file is an image file
        if image_file.endswith('.jpg'):
            image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, image_file)

            # Construct the corresponding XML file path
            xml_file = os.path.join(folder_path, image_file[:-4] + '.xml')

            # Parse the XML file
            image_path, objects = parse_annotation(xml_file)

            # Display the extracted information
            print('Image Path:', image_path)
            for obj in objects:
                print('Class:', obj['class'])
                print('Bounding Box:', obj['bbox'])
```

the output is like so:

```
Image Path: /content/drive/My Drive/Bot_voc/Fujifilm_Persona_jpeg.rf.8ade44be97e02af5b3bfe2a4fe1b4e70.jpg
Class: C_arm
Bounding Box: (67, 118, 294, 384)
```

But whenI try to prepare this object to train  a model:

```
def preprocess_image(image_path, objects, input_shape):
    img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=input_shape[:2])
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = preprocess_input(img)

    # Extract bounding box coordinates and class labels
    boxes = [obj['bbox'] for obj in objects]
    classes = [obj['class'] for obj in objects]

    return img, boxes, classes


def create_dataset(data_dir, input_shape, batch_size=32):
    image_paths = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.path.join(data_dir, '*.jpg'))
    print("image+apths",image_paths)

    def parse_image(image_path):
        image_path_str = image_path.numpy().decode()  # Convert the image_path to a string
        xml_file = image_path_str[:-4] + '.xml'
        image_path, objects = parse_annotation(xml_file)
        img, boxes, classes = preprocess_image(image_path, objects, input_shape)
        print("image+apths",classes)
        return img, boxes, classes

    dataset = image_paths.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(parse_image, [x], [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.string]))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return dataset


# Define your dataset directory path and input shape
data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/ORBot_voc/train'
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)

# Create the dataset
train_dataset = create_dataset(data_dir, input_shape, batch_size=4)

# Display the dataset
for img, boxes, classes in train_dataset:
    print('Image Shape:', img.shape)
    print('Bounding Boxes:', boxes)
    print('Classes:', classes)
```

i get the error file not found

```
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b93e1735de95> in <cell line: 40>()
     38 
     39 # Display the dataset
---> 40 for img, boxes, classes in train_dataset:
     41     print('Image Shape:', img.shape)
     42     print('Bounding Boxes:', boxes)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7260 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7261   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7262   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7263 
   7264 

UnknownError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_3_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My Drive/Bot_voc/download-2-_jpeg.rf.fc7114de1cf2a4fa936ba9dac44e32d4.jpg'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 265, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 143, in __call__
    outputs = self._call(device, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 150, in _call
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "<ipython-input-18-b93e1735de95>", line 21, in parse_image
    img, boxes, classes = preprocess_image(image_path, objects, input_shape)

  File "<ipython-input-18-b93e1735de95>", line 2, in preprocess_image
    img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=input_shape[:2])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/image_utils.py", line 422, in load_img
    with open(path, "rb") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My Drive/Bot_voc/download-2-_jpeg.rf.fc7114de1cf2a4fa936ba9dac44e32d4.jpg'


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```